# Request ump consent always return false on iOS

Tags: ios, admob

You guys have any idea  as to what may be the possible cause of this error  in UMP SDK for iOS?

Request ump consent always return false on iOS.always return UMPFormStatusUnavailable.

And I find that the device id keeps changing,I don't know if this is correct.
To enable debug mode for this device, set: UMPDebugSettings.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ @"xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx" ];

ps:I already configured and allowed those messages for iOS on GDPR.

code just like this

```
void UMP_RequestConsentInformation(FormLoadedFunction callback)
{
    NSLog(@"Request UMP");
    callBackFunction = callback;
    // Create a UMPRequestParameters object.
    UMPRequestParameters *parameters = [[UMPRequestParameters alloc] init];
    // Set tag for under age of consent. Here NO means users are not under age.
    parameters.tagForUnderAgeOfConsent = NO;
    
    UMPDebugSettings *debugSettings = [[UMPDebugSettings alloc] init];
    debugSettings.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ @"XXX-XXX-XXX"];
    debugSettings.geography = UMPDebugGeographyEEA;
    parameters.debugSettings = debugSettings;
    
    //todo remove
    //[UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance reset];
    
    // Request an update to the consent information.
    [[UMPConsentInformation sharedInstance] requestConsentInfoUpdateWithParameters:parameters completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // The consent information has updated.
        if (error) {
            // Handle the error.
            NSLog(@"Request UMP consent informaition error: %@", error);
        }
        else
        {
            // The consent information state was updated.
            // You are now ready to see if a form is available.
            UMPFormStatus formStatus = [[UMPConsentInformation sharedInstance] formStatus];
            if (formStatus == UMPFormStatusAvailable)
            {
                loadForm();
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *formStatusString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)formStatus];
                NSLog(@"UMP consent is not available! %@", formStatusString);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I want to fix this , but dont know how to fix it.

Comment: alreay fix,  I forgot to configured it for iOS on GDPR,  I only configured it for Android.